# How to modify integer template argument to nonzero at compile time?

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

If i have this code:

```
template<int SIZE = 0>
class A {
public:

    union {
        int buf[MagicThing];
        /* ... */
    };
};
```

Is possible in C++ to make some (macro?) called MagicThing which works this way:

- if SIZE > 0 then MagicThing == SIZE
- if SIZE == 0 then MagicThing == 1

At compile time?
(Idealy some short trick without needs of using boost library etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use:

```
int buf[SIZE > 0 ? SIZE : 1];
```

Comment: What if SIZE < 0 ? The condition was "if SIZE > 0 then MagicThing = SIZE, if SIZE = 0 MagicThing = 1"

Comment: unspecified, so implementation specific :-) (1 in my case).

Comment: @jarod42 what a waste.  You could have invoked nasal demons.

Answer (score 4):

You could try this

```
int buf[SIZE == 0 ? 1 : SIZE]
```

and make `SIZE` unsigned, or add a `static_assert` to check that the size is non-negative. You didn't specify what behaviour you want when `SIZE` is less than 0. Presumably that shouldn't happen.

Comment: unsigned is often a bad idea, as the standard mandates turning negative values silently into huge positive ones, which is rarely a good plan.

Comment: @Yakk I agree, and the plain `static_assert` might be a good option. On the other hand, it is conventional to use `std::size_t` for sizes. So one could use an unsigned integer *and* a `static_assert` checking that the size is less than a certain maximum.

Answer (score 1):

(If SIZE will be always 0 or more, change its type to unsigned.)

A crazy sample solution, which perhaps can be used as idea for other situations (using resources of C++11):

```
#include <iostream>

/* General case */
template<unsigned SIZE>
constexpr unsigned MagicThing()
{
   return SIZE;
}

/* Partial specialization when SIZE == 0 */
template<>
constexpr unsigned MagicThing<0>()
{
    return 1;
}

template<unsigned SIZE = 0>
class A {
public:
   int buf[MagicThing<SIZE>()];

   size_t size() const
   {
       return sizeof(buf) / sizeof(int);
   }
};

int main()
{
   A<0> a0;
   A<1> a1;
   A<5> a5;

   std::cout << a0.size() << " " << a1.size() << " " << a5.size() << std::endl;
}

/* Compilation and execution */
$ gcc -std=c++11 sample.cpp
$ ./a.out
1 1 5
```

Other (not the simplest one) possibility would be, using the new `static_if` directive, proposed for the following standard C++14, the next one (I'm not sure if my syntax is correct):

```
template<unsigned SIZE = 0>
class A {
public:
   static_if (SIZE > 0)
     int buf[SIZE];
   else
     int buf[1];

   size_t size() const
   {
       return sizeof(buf) / sizeof(int);
   }
};
```